# SwipeRefreshLayout pull multiple times behaviour (SDK 23)

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have `SwipeRefreshLayout` as like this:

**.xml**:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/haberRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**.java**:

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_color));
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                refreshContent();
            }
        });
```

This allows me to pull `swipeRefresh` **multiple times** and circling animation becomes weird, sometimes it stays on screen without circling:

[image]

On the first pull it appears a bit on top, on second pull it goes down a bit more as like on image.

How to **disable** multiple pull on `SwipeRefresh` while it is already refreshing ?
I guess this does not happen below sdk 23. I am using buildTool 23, targetSdk 23, support-v4:23, appcompat-v7:23.

**Update:** this does not happen if i use `ListView` instead of `RecyclerView`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem was introduced in support-v4 23.0.0 and is caused by the new nested scroll functionality not checking if isRefreshing().

You should extend SwipeRefreshLayout and override onStartNestedScroll function:

```
@Override
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(View child, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    return !isRefreshing() && super.onStartNestedScroll(child, target, nestedScrollAxes);
}
```

Comment: mSwipeRefreshLayout.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);

Answer (score 5):

"support-v4:23.1.0" already fixed this bug.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in appcompat-v7 support library which was introduced in 23.0.0 release.
As a workaround you can disable SwipeRefreshLayout in OnRefreshListener#onRefresh callback and enable it again when data is loaded:

```
private class MyOnRefreshListener implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
        load();
    }

    private void onLoaded() {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you use `onLoaded()`?

Comment: 1 way is to call it on load() method every time, after it is loaded.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is in how SwipeRefreshLayout handles touch events. Proposed solution at least fixes it for cases when onRefresh has been called. I opened a bug in Android bug tracker, we'll see what Google devs say about it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186062

Answer (score 0):

add boolean variable to check your list for refreshing at this moment.

```
if (!refreshing)
refreshContent();
```

Comment: Yes but where, how to know if i am pulling it second time? Besides that i have recyclerView which has pull as well

Comment: My problem is not refreshing content, but swipeRefresh. It should not allow me to pull while it is already refreshig

Comment: hm. Strange. I'm using this too, but i didnt got this troubles. Have you added swipeLayout .setOnRefreshListener(this);?

Answer (score 0):

you could subclass `SwipeRefreshLayout` providing your custom implementation of `canChildScrollUp()`

```
 @Override
public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
   if (isRefreshing()) {
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

of course you should check if your recycler view is showing already its first child and return a value accordingly

Comment: This method is related to if child can be scrolled in certain cases. Does this get called when pulling swipe itself?

Comment: It does. Give it a try

Comment: it compiles now, but still same behaviour

Answer (score -1):

You need to call mSwipeRefreshLayout.stopRefreshing() when you finish to update your data.

```
public void refreshContent() {
...
//end of your "refresh" code

if(mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing())
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.stopRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: I do that, problem is different :)

Comment: Could you please try if it works below v23? There're bunch of stuff that does not work the same way on v23, I also have some problems with it...

Comment: On the other project with buildToolsVersion "22.0.1", targetSdk 22, appcompat-v7:22.1.0' it works properly